# How to use regular expressions in python to capture the characters between two words?

Tags: python, regex, string

How to use regular expressions in python to capture string betwee between two words? In addition, only return the first set that occurs between the two words.

For example, I'd like to capture all the words that are between "Hi" and "Best"

original_string = "text text words Hi there, I need help using regular expressions ,Best Chris more words Hi This is not what I want ,Best"

desired_string = "there, I need help using regular expressions ,"

I know you use this: (?s)(?<=start_delim).+?(?=end_delim) for c# and replacing start_delim and end_delim as required.

So far I'm trying to search for the two words with search:

```
 b = re.search("Hi(.*?)/Best", a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the [`group`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) method to return the matched string:

```
>>> import re
>>> original_string = "text text words Hi there, I need help using regular expressions ,Best Chris more words Hi This is not what I want ,Best"
>>> desired_string = re.search("(?s)(?<=Hi).+?(?=Best)", original_string).group()
>>> desired_string
' there, I need help using regular expressions ,'
>>>
```